# Is it possible to mediate Millennial Media through Admob

Tags: android, admob

I have configured `admob` with `flurry` and `adfalcon`by creating an instance of their provided adapter class.

```
adBuilder.addNetworkExtras(flurryAdapter);
```

Now just wanted to integrate `Millennial Media` as well, I have googled a lot may be not searching the right term.

1. Is it possible to integrate Millennial Media in/with Admob?
2. If yes, What would be the adapter name?

All I can find is these line of help, there is not a single word about Millennial except the heading itself
http://docs.millennialmedia.com/android-ad-sdk/mediation-admob-to-millennial.html

**Using both Millennial and Legacy Nexage**

> If you are a legacy Nexage account holder or were provided a Site ID
>   by your account manager, an added piece of code is required to
>   communicate this Site ID:

```
Bundle siteId = new Bundle();
siteId.putString("dcn", "<YOUR_SITE_ID>"); // Replace with a SiteID/DCN
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addNetworkExtrasBundle(NexageAdapter.class, siteId)
        .build();
```

Android studio automatically remove this line

```
import com.google.ads.mediation.millennial.MillennialAdapterExtras;
```

What on earth is required to run this code

```
MillennialAdapterExtras millennialExtras = new MillennialAdapterExtras();
millennialExtras.setIncomeInUsDollars(65000);
adRequest.setNetworkExtras(millennialExtras);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can can integrate MillennialMedia.

You don't need any special adapter unless you want to pass Millennial some Millennial specific attributes.

1. All you need to do is to include the Milllenial library in your APK
2. Create a Millenial Ad Unit on the Millenial site
3. Add Millennial as one of the mediation networks in your Admob Ad Unit (on Admob's site) and configure it with your Millenial Ad unit id.

Comment: I just want admob to handle millennialmedia just like flurry and adfalcon

Comment: Exactly. So follow the steps I outlined above.

Comment: And no millennial related code on android device (millennial adapter as i have added others)
`adBuilder.addNetworkExtras(flurryAdapter);`
`adBuilder.addNetworkExtras(adfalconAdapter);`

Comment: That is correct. You don't need those others either. They are only there to allow to provide *extra* information to those ad networks, if you choose to.